# comparison between kdb+/q and onetick for market data

Tags: time-series, kdb

Has anybody done a complete comparison between kdb+/q and onetick for market data? Mainly in terms of cost? Problem with kx seems to be that they push a lot of products which makes it way expensive as compared to alternatives like onetick which are although very low on features, prove cost effective for small institutions.

Comment: It's going to be hard to get a definitive cost comparison because there is no one-size-fits-all product. I don't know much about one-tick personally. You can in theory get a single core kdb license, you don't need the extra products being pushed - the question is whether or not this is enough for your needs and/or whether or not you have the resources and developers to use it. Kx also provide an on-demand licensing model so you only pay for what you use, but then kdb developers likely cost more so you'd have to factor that in too. There's too many variables to get one answer I think

Comment: Despite my biases I 100% agree with Terry here. It's important to remember that the Kx Product Suite *is not kdb+*, it uses kdb+, but as Terry said, you can just use 'vanilla kdb+'. Developing in kdb+ often do cost more than a python developer, but if you have a smaller footprint, then you likely need less development time.

Comment: If you want an idea of the cost of just using kdb+ without the platform, then you can look at the on-demmand solutions https://kx.com/connect-with-us/licenses/. It might also be worth looking at the cloud solutions  https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/kx-kdb-vm-public/kdb, https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/Kx-kdb/B07KX973GH.

Onetick have a similar aws solution, which might allow you to get an idea of the cost difference when using vanilla kdb. https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B08675P3X3?ref_=srh_res_product_title

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. I will expolre the option of building on top of a vanilla kdb+ setup according to the demand. Also, the aws solution looks good.

Comment: If you would like to run kdb+ without any of the additional kx products you should take a look at torq which is open source: https://github.com/AquaQAnalytics/TorQ.